# Location.startGeofencingAsync is sending a bunch of updates at start

Tags: react-native, expo, geofencing

I'm new using [Geofence API](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/docs/pages/versions/unversioned/sdk/location.md#geofencing)

I have some location and I want to detect when user enter or exit from one of them using this function 
[`Location.startGeofencingAsync(taskName, regions)`](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/docs/pages/versions/unversioned/sdk/location.md#locationstartgeofencingasynctaskname-regions)

```
TaskManager.defineTask(YOUR_TASK_NAME, ({ data: { eventType, region }, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    // check `error.message` for more details.
    return;
  }
  if (eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Enter) {
    console.log("You've entered region:", region);
  } else if (eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Exit) {
    console.log("You've left region:", region);
  }
});
```

But I'm facing the following **problem:**

When I grant location permission automatically I get the status of each region.

Example:

- I have two locations registered and my current position is out of all of then,
- I received two notification on the console: `You've left region: {...}`

So, I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to avoid the notification of all of my locations (regions) when the user grants location permission?
2. If I turn off the location and turn it on again I get the notification of all my locations (regions) two times. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

When you specify the `regions` array when you call `Location.startGeofencingAsync()`, each region within the array has a `notifyOnExit` property which is optional but defaults to `true`.

Set `notifyOnExit` to `false` and you should find you no longer receive an update when you leave the region (or when geofencing starts and you're already out of the region).